# Positioning filament group buttons?

Tags: css, positioning

I would like to properly position buttons right beside dropdown (see picture bellow), any comments?

[problem http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/2294/positioningproblemwithf.png](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/2294/positioningproblemwithf.png)

[Click to View FullPicture](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/2294/positioningproblemwithf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to float the dropdown too.

Another approach would be to put the buttons in a container which is displayed inline.

Comment: Thanks Ken, 
I floated dropdown and that solved the problem, but I'm curious why buttons were not positioned properly before, even after I modified their's containg block display style to inline?

Comment: If you could put up a sample page then I'd be happy to look into it.